# What is the correct use of overloading functions in TypeScript with the use of subtypes?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am relatively new to TypeScript and have written some types and interfaces for some React components. Now I am struggling with some TypeScript errors for the following code:

```js
import { RadioGroup } from "@headlessui/react";
import { CheckCircleIcon } from "@heroicons/react/20/solid";
import { JSX, isValidElement, memo } from "react";

type RadioOptionObject = {
  title?: string | JSX.Element;
  description?: string | JSX.Element;
};

type RadioOption = RadioOptionObject | JSX.Element | string;

interface RadioOptionsProps {
  gridClasses?: string;
  className?: string;

  canDeselect?: boolean;

  options: ReadonlyArray<RadioOption>;
  selected: RadioOption | RadioOption[];

  onChange: (option: RadioOption) => void;
  compareBy?: (optionA: RadioOption, optionB: RadioOption) => boolean;

  getKey?: (option: RadioOption, index?: number) => string;

  // getOptionLabel?: (option: RadioOption) => string | JSX.Element;
  getOptionLabel?(option: string): string;
  getOptionLabel?(option: JSX.Element): JSX.Element;
  getOptionLabel?(option: RadioOptionObject): string | JSX.Element;
}

function isJSXElement(option: unknown): option is JSX.Element {
  return isValidElement(option);
}

function isOptionObject(option: unknown): option is RadioOptionObject {
  return !(typeof option === "string" || isJSXElement(option));
}

const RadioOptions = memo(
  function RadioOptions({
    options,
    selected,
    className,
    gridClasses = "sm:grid-cols-2 grid-cols-1",
    canDeselect = false,
    onChange,
    compareBy,
    getKey = (_option, index) => `option${index}`,
    getOptionLabel = (option) =>
/*  ^ 
    Type '(option: string | Element | RadioOptionObject) => string | Element' is not assignable to type '{ (option: string): string; (option: Element): Element; (option: RadioOptionObject): string | Element; }'.
    Type 'string | Element' is not assignable to type 'string'.
    Type 'Element' is not assignable to type 'string'. */
    
      isOptionObject(option) ? option.title || "" : option,
  }: RadioOptionsProps) {
...
```

I have tried it without overriding functions `getOptionLabel?: (option: RadioOption) => string | JSX.Element;` and here I see no errors, but I don't understand the difference.

Also in the latter case where I don't get any TypeScript errors within the component I get some on usage. That could be seen as a separate question but it's kinda in the same context so...

```js
<RadioOptions
  className="mb-4 -sm:order-3 -sm:mt-4 -sm:w-full"
  options={exerciseTypes}
  selected={chosenTypes}
  // type ExerciseType = "strength" | "stretch" | "cardio"
  getOptionLabel={(option: ExerciseType) => {
/*^
  Type '(option: ExerciseType) => JSX.Element' is not assignable to type '(option: RadioOption) => string | Element'.
  Types of parameters 'option' and 'option' are incompatible.
  Type 'RadioOption' is not assignable to type '"strength" | "stretch" | "cardio"'.
*/
    const label = capitalizeText(option);
    const exerciseCount = exercisesForEquipmentAndDifficulty.filter(
      (e) => e.type === option
    ).length;

    return (
      <span>
        {label}
        <br />
        <span className="text-xs text-gray-500">({exerciseCount})</span>
      </span>
    );
  }}
  gridClasses="grid-cols-3"
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Overloaded function types don't mix very well with function expressions.  The easiest way to define your function while keeping it typesafe is to declare it as a standalone function:

```js
function myGetOptionLabel(option: string): string;
function myGetOptionLabel(option: JSX.Element): JSX.Element;
function myGetOptionLabel(option: RadioOptionObject): string | JSX.Element;
function myGetOptionLabel(option: string | JSX.Element | RadioOptionObject): string | JSX.Element {
    return isOptionObject(option) ? option.title || "" : option;
}
```

Yes, this is verbose.

An alternative is to define a separate type for the overloaded function and use a type assertion (`as`) on the function expression:

```js
type GetOptionLabelT = {
  (option: string): string;
  (option: JSX.Element): JSX.Element;
  (option: RadioOptionObject): string | JSX.Element;
};

interface RadioOptionsProps {
  getOptionLabel?: GetOptionLabelT;
};

var props: RadioOptionsProps = {
  getOptionLabel: ((option) => isOptionObject(option) ? option.title || "" : option) as GetOptionLabelT
};
```

But note that this is not typesafe.

You could also take a step back and question whether it's useful to have such an overloaded function type.

Comment: I like the first solution you proposed but I seem to struggle building it in. Can you provide an example how to use the overloaded function as a property?

Or did I fundamentally write weird code?

Comment: @Wallek: I don't think I understand what you mean. You should be able to just write `{/*blabla*/ selected={chosenTypes}, getOptionLabel: myGetOptionLabel, /* blabla etc.*/}` to pass a reference to the function in the RadioOptionsProps object.

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarifying. I thought so, tried it and still receive the same TypeScript errors.
Maybe I made some fundamental mistakes.

Comment: @Wallek If you need more help, I suggest that you create a minimal example and upload it to the TypeScript playground. That makes it easier to see what you're doing and what error you get.